# Load template/html in require.js with text plugin

Tags: html, node.js, templates, requirejs, optimization

Since two days I try to load a template in require.js using the text plugin, but I can't manage that.

```
define(['jquery', 'text!myView.html'], function ($, myView) {...
```

Produces the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load

So I put myView.html to a local Webserver and enabled CORS

```
define(['jquery', 'text!http://localhost/myView.html'], function ($, myView){...
```

Produces the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Google told me, I should use the requirejs optimizer, which produces a .js out of my html file. This should solve the problem.

To be honest, I really don't undertand what to write in the build.js.
It's so confusing to me. Here is an example build.js: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

The only thing I know is that "optimizeAllPluginResources" option has to be true. But what about all the other options?

build.js:

```
({
paths: {
   myView: "myView.html"
},
optimizeAllPluginResources: true,
name: "myView",
out: "myView.js"})
```

..doens't work

Let me summarize: I only want to optimize a single html file, to use it my Application, nothing else.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The `text!` plugin does work without optimization. You should check with your browser's dev tools' network tab that the URL requirejs uses to fetch `myView.html` is correct. If it's not, you'll need to fix your path configuration or use a path in the dependency array, e.g.: `text!templates/views/myView.html`

Comment: I checked the URL and it is correct.

Comment: So from which line you get the syntax error?

Comment: The second define line you can see in my post produces the uncaught syntay error. Do you know what to write in the build.js for the optimizer?

Comment: I can not explain the build configuration any better than what the example you linked to does. There are no syntax errors in the second define line of your post. Please include the entire error (stack trace) exactly as it shows up in developer tools console. Use unminified RequireJS and `text!` if possible. See here for [debugging help](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).